# display values in variable using get or paste0 function

Tags: r

I am trying to get values from variable `wtype1` using `paste0` but I am getting only the name of variable instead of values.

```
> a <- data.frame(wtype1=c(1:4))

> paste0("a$wtype",1)
> "a$wtype1"
```

I also tried using the `get` function with `paste0`

```
> get(paste0("a$wtype",1))
Error in get(paste0("a$wtype",1)) : object 'a$wtype1' not found
```

**Edited Question**

I have a data frame with 1000 row and 10 columns. I have to calculate zscores for wtype1  wtype2  wtype3  wtype4  wtype5 and case1  case2 case3 case4 case5 separately for each row. here is a dummy example of my data frame

```
> data     
gene  wtype1  wtype2  wtype3  wtype4  wtype5  case1  case2 case3 case4 case5
A1CF    56       40     50     45      30      2       10    22     23    16 
........
```

The resulted data frame would look like (these values are just assumed)

```
> zscores.data
 gene  wtype1  wtype2  wtype3  wtype4  wtype5  case1  case2  case3  case4  case5
 A1CF    2.1     1.1     1.7     1.4    0.6   -0.04  -0.08   -0.2    0.25 -0.09
 ........
```

Comment: Why cant you use `a$wtype1[1]` or `a[1, 'wtype']`?  If you want to parse a string, `eval(parse(text='a$wtype[1]'))`  To create the `string`, you may use `paste` function, but I wouldn't use `eval(parse`

Comment: you want the values and then use the `paste0` function. It is not clear to me your goal. Could you please be more specific? And more important, why you quote the first argument of the `paste0` ?

Comment: Or, for overkill, `print(a$wtype1)`

Comment: as for using `get`, which I highly doubt is necessary for what you seem to be going after, `a[["wtype1"]]` should also get what you're after

Comment: Do you just want to display the values of the data.frame?

Comment: @SabDeM I have columns in a data frame (wtype1 wtype2 wtype3 wtype4 wtype5) on each column I have to do certain operations. For this reason I have to call each column name using paste0 function in loop.

Comment: It might be better if you provide more details about the kind of operations you want to do.  YOu may not need to do this `paste` stuff

Comment: paste0 function is used to concatenate strings. It is most commonly used in data frame to combine multiple strings into a single character string. Using this function to call data from column is really far fetched... I doubt if it can be done either...

Comment: By the way u can just remove those quotes and try watever you want to do... `paste0(a$wtype,1)` ... When you say "a$wtype" you are referring to a string which has the characeters "a$type" and not your data...

Comment: @akrun I have edited the question above.

Comment: You can use `lapply` to do this i.e. `data[grep('wtype|case', names(data))] <- lapply(data[grep('wtype|case', names(data))], function(x) ....)`

Comment: @akrun I didn't understand your solution

Comment: It was calculating the scores for each column separately.  Do you want to calculate the scores for 'wtype' separately for each row and 'case' for each row?  In that case, `apply(data[grep('wtype', names(data))], 1, function(x) ...)` calculate it for each row.  and you can replace it with 'case' in the `grep` for calculating the zscore on that

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `grep` to find the columns that starts with 'wtype' and 'case' separately, and then run the function in OP' post for each row of the subset of columns by using `MARGIN=1` in the `apply` loop.

```
apply(data[grep('^wtype', names(data))], 1, yourfunction)
apply(data[grep('^case', names(data))], 1, yourfunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand your problem correctly but here is what I would do. I assume that your data.frame is represented by

```
a <- structure(list(wtype1 = c(4.9, 3.1, 6.6), wtype2 = c(7.6, 9, 4.4), wtype3 = c(3.8, 8.7, 6.1), wtype4 = c(9.1, 6, 2.6), wtype5 = c(8.7, 2.7, 6.5), wtype6 = c(1.9, 2.8, 0.4), wtype7 = c(9.3, 4.3, 0.9), wtype8 = c(7, 5.3, 1), wtype9 = c(4.3, 1.4, 1.7), wtype10 = c(9.1, 3.5, 1.4)), .Names = c("wtype1", "wtype2", "wtype3", "wtype4", "wtype5", "wtype6", "wtype7", "wtype8", "wtype9", "wtype10"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

In this case you could select the columns you need to work on simply with (for example):

```
a[ colnames( a ) == "wtype3" ]
   wtype3
1     3.8
2     8.7
3     6.1
```

and do your operations with the columns. For more detailed advice we would need to know the exact structure of your data.frame.